# indentation with linux command line tools

Tags: shell, echo

i'm currently writing a linux script that has the following code:

```
echo "\nCompiled on:\n `gcc --version`\n"
```

the output is formatted as such:

```
Compiled on:
gcc (GCC) 3.4.4 etc...
This is free software...
```

however i want the command to be formatted like this:

```
Compiled on:
    gcc(GCC) 3.4.4 etc...
    This is free software...
```

how can i format the text so that each LINE outputted from the `gcc --version` command has its own tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
echo "\nCompiled on:\n $(gcc --version | sed 's/^/\t/g' )\n"
```

The output of `gcc --version` is piped to `sed`, which adds a tab at the beginning of the line.

Alternatively, you could use awk (could be shorter if you don't need the extra newlines):

```
gcc --version | awk 'BEGIN { print "\nCompiled on:" } { print "\t" $0 } END { printf RS }'
```

Comment: fantastic thanks. i hate being so ignorant on using regexps and awk.